# How to put a GSM modem (e.g. SIM900A) to sleep mode?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, gsm, at-command, sleep-mode

As you probably guessed this question is not about a programming language but about arduino.

I'm making a big project which includes a GSM SIM900A module but it draws too much power.

I've looked up the datasheet but I didn't understand a lot as it references a DTR pin, something my module doesn't have.

Can someone tell me how to put it to sleep mode?

Any help will be grately appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While you put it in sleep mode it is ok, for you, to switch of its RF capabilities?

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand what you are saying

Comment: There are different *types* of sleep mode. In some of them the modem keeps to be synchronized to the network... but I'm not sure they are supported by your module. Some other types basically turn off Radio Frequency capabilities (but keeps being responsive to AT port). This mode is supported. Is it ok for you?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!
Yes, it's ok for me.
Do you want me to post an image of the module?

Answer (score 1):

The GSM standard AT command for the setting of modem's level of functionality is `AT+CFUN`.

According to [SIM900 AT commands guide](http://www.jechavarria.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/SIM900-AT-Commands-Manual_V1.07.pdf) its syntax is

> **AT+CFUN=fun[,rst]**

Where:

- **fun**: is the power saving mode
- **rst**: is the reset flag

There are several possible values of `fun` parameter that can be supported or not depending on the modem vendor.

In order to reduce power consumption, SIM900A offers two possibilities:

1. `AT+CFUN=0`, means that the device is in sleep mode, and the AT interface is not accessible. **Usually** it keeps its network paging activities and its registration status to the network (it's not really clear from SIM900 guide). The device is woken up as soon as a wake up event occurs (for example an incoming SMS). Test it on your device.
2. `AT+CFUN=4`, that disable both TX and RX RF circuits. The AT interface remains reachable.

Usually first solution results in a bigger reduction of power consumption, but I suggest trying both of them in your specific board in order to understand what is the better choice for you.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out!

Comment: @Stevros Bravas let me know.

Comment: So I tried putting the module to sleep mode but I didn't see any difference in power consumption. Im using a multimeter to measure the consumption. Maybe my code is wrong. Can you suggest me a solution? Maybe show me your code or something?

Comment: Both the options? Sounds strange! Have you tried it providing the commands *manually* (and not programmatically?  How are consumptions if compared to those with the modem completely switched off?

Comment: With the modem switched off the power consumption is 39 mA. How can I make a circuit where I can provide commads manually? What I mean is that only got a simple multimeter to measure the consumption...

Comment: @Stavros Baras Ps: unfortunately I don't have code to share. I know AT standard because I work for a cellular modules vendor, but I cannot guarantee anything for the funtionalities of other vendor's product. Anyway, +CFUN is a really common standard command, so sounds strange that they implemented it in a dummy way.

Comment: 39mA switched off. And with all the others +cfun configurations? (+cfun=0/1/4)

Comment: That's what Im not sure about. Am I using the right commands to put it to sleep mode? How can I be sure?

Comment: 1) what was the consumption before trying to provide +CFUN=0 or +CFUN=4? 2) Am I wrong or Arduino tools provide a serial port logger allowing to trace the serial port traffic? 3) Manual commands can be provided if you manage to connect modem's UART to your PC (COM port)

Comment: 4) AT communication code should simply send commands and always wait for responses. In this case `\r\nOK\r\n`

Comment: So in every single case (CFUN=0/1/4) the power consumption is about 75 for some seconds and after that its 60-62 mA.

Comment: I also know how to provide manual commands but I don't know how to do it along with using my multimeter to measure the consumption.

Comment: It seems like there's something preventing the modem to actually start power saving. I cannot guess it. In order to measure current you have to connect your multimeter in series with power supply (either + or -; it should be the same). I don't understand why this connection is preventing you from the capability to send manual commands.

Comment: Actually can you provide the code to send manual commands? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Update: when I use the command to put it to sleep mode it returns OK but also "+CPIN: NOT READY".

Comment: That seems the response of `AT+CPIN?` command (though a strange one). Did you previously send it in your program? In this case you might have some old data in the rx input from the modem.  Always read it or, at least, flush it before reading +cfun answer.

Comment: Im completely buffled. I send AT its sends back ok. I do after some time again it does nothing. Oh boy...

Comment: I don't remember by heart. There's probably a *function* doing this in Arduino library for serial management. Chech Arduino API guide.